# Composer install create folders in second time only

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

I have a problème with composer install, if I launch the last command, it creates the vendor folder in my Laravel 5 project, and all its dependencies, but doesn't create folders what I want to some folders at the same time.
I added the following lines to my composer.json file:

```
"post-install-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
        "php artisan optimize",
        "mkdir public/kit",
        "mkdir public/files",
        "mkdir public/sites"
    ],
```

The problem is, that if I launch the same command (composer install) a second time, It said:

> Loading composer repositories with package information
>   Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
>   Nothing to install or update
>   Generating autoload files
>   Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postInstall
>   php artisan optimize
>   Generating optimized class loader
>   Compiling common classes
>   mkdir public/kit
>   mkdir public/files
>   mkdir public/sites

And It creates the folders what I need ...
Any help please?
Thanks alot

Comment: Does the first execution of Composer generate any error messages? Does it exit 0, or with another value?

Comment: No, the first composer install works good :)

Answer (score 2):

The "post-install-cmd" needs to be placed inside the "scripts" root entry:

```
"scripts": {

    "post-install-cmd": [
       "mkdir public/kit",
       "..."
    ],

    "post-update-cmd": [
       "UPDATE ACTIONS",
       "..."
    ],
}
```

Answer (score -2):

you can install composer only one time.
after installation you can update composer.
commond :- `composer update`

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I know this point, but my problem, is that composer install doesn't create folders what I need from the first time, I need to re-launch the command a second time for that ... 
Thanks in anyway